# javascript JQuery similar selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, methods, selector

Hello guys I want to have something like JQuery selectors. What I mean is this:

JQuery has a selector something like this:

```
$("#exampleID").JQexampleMethod();
```

I want to have something similar for my class. for example

```
selector("#exampleID").MYexampleMethod();
```

but I can't find out how to do this. I know how to create class and define them. But can't achieve my needs. So far what I have done is this:

```
var class = new TestClass();
class.selector("#exampleID").MyExampleMethod();
```

Comment: You want to create a jQuery plugin? That is, invoke `MyExampleMethod` for all elements that match the given selector?

Comment: no I don't want to create jquery plugin. I want to have my own class that uses similar method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that easy to replicate jQuery because it contains of all kinds of fixes for cross-browser issues and even a whole selector library.

That said, if you disregard those issues, a simple prototype can be as follows:

```
var selector = function(selector) {
  var res = document.querySelectorAll(selector);  // fetch elements
  res.myExampleMethod = function() {  // add a method
    return res.length;
  };
  return res;
};
```

You could use it as follows:

```
selector("p").myExampleMethod();  // e.g. 12
```

Comment: However, it's only supported in IE8 and later: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector If you need to support IE7, you need to use a library like Sizzle.

Comment: It doesn't metter, I will find some fixes

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses the [Sizzle library](http://sizzlejs.com/) to evaluate the selectors.

Comment: Unless `querySelectorAll` is available.

Comment: It does't mater what library uses this method. I just can't find out how to create similar for my class

Comment: @Irakli: The library doesn't use that method, it *provides* that method. It is what jQuery uses to get the functionality.